# update time for every minute using services

Tags: android, service

i want to update the time for every minute using services in android. so please tell me how to do that one .

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: tha important thing: alarmmanager is NOT a good choice, because it does not work correctly, alarms are not recovered on restart of phone and many other discusting things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use alarmservice in your service.

Here is an example for that http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html